# How to prove a polynomial cannot be factored?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Is there any way to prove that a polynomial has no rational factors?

Comment: A start here: Rational Zero Theorem?

Comment: Also Eisenstein's Criterion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion

Comment: Juan, you have an example in mind?

Comment: The answer to your question is Yes. But there are many approaches, each most appropriate to a certain class of polynomials. This is a big subject.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials